# No index, no follow - URL Customer Account

Tags: magento2, no-index, no-follow

I have recently created a store view for my English version and I have seen that the urls of
"/uk/customer/account/login..."

Is there any way to not position this type of url, that is, tell google no index, no follow?

Thanks!

Version: Magento 2.4.2

Comment: means you want to disallow my account page to google?

Comment: Here is the FREE extension that you can use - https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-seo-suite

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the store configuration settings,

```
Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Url Option -> Add Store Code to Urls -> NO
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

But what I really want is that any url that has "uk/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM..." is not positioned in google.

With the answer that you understand that any url that is from the UK will not be positioned.

It's right?

Answer (score 0):

I have created an extension that fixes the core Magento SEO issues:

- Adds canonical URL to the homepage, CMS pages, and contact us page
- Eliminates non-canonical product URLs from sitemap.xml
- Offers HTML sitemap creation
- Enables SEO pagination using rel="prev" and rel="next" meta tags
- Adds "NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW" meta robots to `/customer`, /checkout, and /catalogsearch pages

You can download it from GitHub - https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-seo-suite

Answer (score 0):

To prevent search engines like Google from indexing pages like  `customer/account/login/*`, `customer/account/create/` and `customer/account/forgotpassword` you will have to set a `noindex/nofollow` tag to the `<head>` section of those pages.

1. Go to `app/design/frontend/Your_namespace/your_theme/Magento_Theme/layout/`
2. Create `customer_account_login.xml`, `customer_account_create.xml` and `customer_account_forgotpassword.xml` files
3. Add the following code to each of those files

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
       <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
   </head>
   ```
4. Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` **(when in production mode)** and `php bin/magento cache:flush` commands

Check the frontend of your store. The `<head>` section of said pages should now contain the `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">` tag.